# How to create a new random API Key for the user with permissions assigned making cURL POST request

Tags: php, http, post, curl, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to run a POST to SendGrid's API to get an Authentication User API Key, but I don't think I'm understanding how posting with a body actually works in PHP. SendGrid has given me the following information that I need to make the call in HTML:

**Request**:

```
POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/api_keys HTTP/1.1
```

**Request Body**:

```
{
  "name": "My API Key",
  "scopes": [
    "mail.send",
    "alerts.create",
    "alerts.read"
  ]
}
```

Here is ***my*** code:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/api_keys';

$body = array(
    "name" => "My API Key",
    "scopes" => array(
        "mail.send",
        "alerts.create",
        "alerts.read"
    )
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($body));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type'=>'application/json'));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result."\n";

$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

$if ($status != 200){
    die('Error with request: '.$status);
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

This is the error message I receive when executing the file:

> `{"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"authorization required"}]}1`
>
> `Error with request: 401`

What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/How_To_Use_The_Web_API_v3/authentication.html

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. If someone could please explain that to me I'll be happy to fix it.

Comment: Because the error message should be rather self-explanatory. You need to provide authorization, as described in the documentation section Iinked to above. If you could make that call your are trying to make, which  [_"will create a new random API Key for the user with permissions assigned"_](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/API_Keys/index.html#Generate-a-new-API-Key-for-the-authenticated-user-POST) without authorization, then how would the API even know _which user_ to create a key for?

Comment: Okay, I have changed the title.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/api_keys';

$body = array(
            "name" => "My API Key",
            "scopes" => array(
                "mail.send",
                "alerts.create",
                "alerts.read"
            )
        );
$myArray = array(
                'Content-type'=>'application/json',
                'Authorization'=> 'Bearer Your.A;PI.Key-HERE'
            );

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($body));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $myArray);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result."\n";

$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

$if ($status != 200){
    die('Error with request: '.$status);
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```